# How to deal with questions that require a significant amount of reserach?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205229/detection-and-tracking-of-vehicle-in-open-cv?) question. This question requires some painstaking research to be dome before someone can answer it. As the OP points out in the comment she is seeking mere opinions who have done similar kind of work. I am very sure, the number of people who have done such work are not a very significant number and out of those who have done it, it's very unlikely that she will end up finding 2 or 3 of them here. What's the way to deal with this kind? Aren't they off topic at SO?

Comment: Because it's not anymore about programming.

Comment: Its a poor question, completely unspecific, but the fact it requires research has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @OGHaza I guess I misused the term research. With research I meant something like thinking over, reading journals, conference papers etc before reaching a conclusion

Comment: At best it is a homework question, nobody actually launches cars at pedestrians to test their code.  At worst it is a figment of the OP's imagination, lots of SO users have wild project ideas but don't know how to get started on them.  That doesn't otherwise make it off topic, Google didn't think so, merely very unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 5):

No, questions are not off-topic simply because they are hard to answer.

Questions are only off-topic for the reasons named in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions that require a lot of work to answer perhaps just won't get an answer, unless someone is willing to put in the work.

The question you linked to may well be off-topic because it is too vague and too broad to be answered, not because it might be *hard* to answer. If a question requires a whole book to explain, it is too broad. If there is a short and concise answer, it is not.

Comment: May be because its not anymore about programming

Comment: @bubble, if your question asked "how to deal with questions that aren't about programming", you'd have received a different answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the specific question you use as an example...

If a question requires a significant amount of research there are two ways to deal with it:

1. Don't do the research and don't answer the question
2. Do the research and do answer the question

The amount of research required to answer a question should be, at most, something you use to decide whether you want to answer the question or not. I tend to like questions that require a lot of research because there's a good chance I'll learn a fair bit in answering them and they're normally a lot more interesting than others.

The likelihood of obtaining an answer should not be taken into account. To put this more bluntly; please do not turn away "difficult" questions - the site will be extremely boring if that happens.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't a question get an extra bonus for being difficult? Difficult questions are, in general, more useful than easy questions, aren't they?

Comment: I'm not sure that they're more _useful_ @Jan; but that depends how you define usefulness (amount of hours saved?) But, yes. If someone asks a difficult question please upvote! Let's fight the "debug this for me" culture.

Comment: @Ben I kind of felt "debug this for me" when I read the question. Won't it be like I do all the research and the research paper goes in the name of OP. We need to discern a bit more.