# How to reduce and quickly close questions that are merely requirements?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I can't even count how many times a question is downvoted and closed because it's merely a dump of OP's wishes or requirements without any attempt to solve his problem and/or debug his program. Just for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719882/i-want-to-know-which-checkbox-is-selected-first) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723834/read-and-down-load-as-zip-file-using-url-in-asp-net), but we all see **many** every single day. The problem with these questions is that they're (also) seldom useful to someone else, (like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713279/how-to-make-this-code-work-with-ipad#comment40195391_25713279)). A poorly asked question can be downvoted (because OP didn't give any effort), but also answered (because someone else may find it very useful).

Sometimes they know *how to ask a good question*, but they're *help vampires*, so downvoting and closing their questions is a good idea. Sometimes, they're just newbies used to other sites and they don't know SO *guidelines* about questions. To both help them and to keep the site *tidy*, I'm thinking about two very small changes:

### Change help text in "Ask Question" page

Now it's:

> How to Ask
>   Is your question about programming?
>   We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>   Provide details. Share your research.
>   If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

I understand it must be concise (otherwise no one will ever read it) but a little bit more detail will help them (is there any stat about how many people clicked *help* link from that page?). Something like this (it's just an idea to highlight concept):

> Questions about programming that can be answered (not just discussed) are preferred and encouraged. Provide **as much detail as needed** to understand your problem and don't forget to include any **relevant code** you wrote (questions with a **raw dump of your requirements or wishes are seldom answered**).

Benefits: they'll immediately know what they should do to write a well-accepted question (if they ignore, then the *normal* path to closure will work). This will help newbies and keep the close queue shorter. They may even post their questions in another site if they want a ready-to-use solution; in this case, they don't waste their and our time. Also see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039) to add a more descriptive warning (when question text appears to be too poor).

Drawbacks: nothing I can think about.

---

**EDIT**
A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740536/i-need-to-convert-arrays-in-xml?noredirect=1#comment40247161_25740536) I saw today made me think about something else that should be pretty easy to implement. Any question that contains *"ASAP"* or *"it's urgent"* or *"provide me code"* should trigger a big red alert in the *Ask Question* page. Something like:

> People here may write some code to solve your issue or simply provide a working solution without a single line of code. They'll try to help you to solve your problem but you shouldn't expect they do your job (unless they feel that will also help someone else in future). Moreover they do it for free so if you're in hurry you should - instead of seeking help - hire them.

**EDIT 2**:
Don't you feel that day by day you spend more time to close question than to answer them? I don't even speak about questions quality, just the number of (*lazy people*) questions that doesn't *deserve* any answer. **More SO will be popular and more it will attract these questions, do we want rep w@@@@ to answer them all or do we want to (try) to keep SO a better place? Don't we need a better tool to discourage both these questions and these answers?**

As pointed out by raedwald there are other questions on meta about this topic (for example [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)) discussing about the right close reason for this questions. Frankly speaking...who cares? Even a close reason *"Please read FAQ before asking"* will work for these questions, what I would have is a tool to quickly wipe them.

---

### RequirementsDumpHammer

Dupes are easily closed by DupeHammer, I think a gold badge user should also have privileges to quickly close such questions (with the proper motivation according to current SO guidelines for that: off-topic XYZ? Unclear what you're asking?). Also discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251646/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-require-a-significant-amount-of-reserach) (for example). Sometimes I try to answer them (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034413/number-of-maximum-array-member-in-powershell/25035092#25035092) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643017/localize-text-on-one-page-in-mvc/25643388#25643388)) when I feel *someone else* may also find it useful, but I can't deny that a decent answer is much more useful (and concise) if tied to a proper question.

Benefits: such questions will be quickly closed (and they won't attract low quality answers in the hope to catch 10/20 rep points). This will discourage both to ask such questions and to answer them. Moreover close queue will be smaller.

Drawbacks: if DupeHammer is accepted and in use, then there's nothing wrong with extending the "hammer" power to other close reasons. IMO it's much easier to detect a very poor question (especially if very specific and without any use for future readers) than a duplicate.

As discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256537/extending-the-gold-badge-rights-to-further-close-vote-reasons) there is some concern about superpowers but idea itself may be joined with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258131/relax-close-vote-requirements-for-low-quality-questions) to have:

- If question has score of zero or more then normal rules apply (five close votes).
- If question has a negative score than RequirementsDumpHammer applies and question can be closed with a single gold badge user.
- If question is closed by this hammer then it's also automatically marked to be deleted. This will quickly wipe such questions but it'll also give an extra visibility to them (reviewers will still be able to detect a bad vote, in the remote case).

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Rethinking the torrent of trash: quarantine for new user questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270304/839601)

Comment: Slightly related: I've previously suggested a tutorial to educate users about the difference between good & bad posts: [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly)

Comment: also: [Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039)

Comment: @Tanner my +1, I think some bad questions may be avoided with a good concise always visible help/tips. For the others a quick _wipe_ feature will do the job. I embedded a link to your meta question, I think it may help on this!

Comment: If you downvote an answer, and no one answers it - it will eventually get closed and deleted automatically. Just downvote and move on.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I saw in the last 1 hour at least three questions like that. Poor and lazy questions (basically: "write code for me"). At least two of them have two or more answers.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: The new ones I have to search them but you have examples in my question: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723834/read-and-down-load-as-zip-file-using-url-in-asp-net) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719882/i-want-to-know-which-checkbox-is-selected-first)

Comment: Downvote them, downvote the answers too. They will be automatically deleted, no additional action required.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I don't think you should downvote the answer. There can be good/useful answers to bad questions.

Comment: @Neolisk if the answer can be useful then you shouldn't really be using the question. You should downvote answers if they're not useful to the site. If they are - don't.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it's not always true (well in those cases it's OK to downvote both, IMO). Question itself can be _bad_ (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034413/number-of-maximum-array-member-in-powershell/25035092#25035092)) but to deserve an answer (in that case [I posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25035092/1207195) as Community Wiki because I think it may be really useful for someone else in future even if OP didn't do any effort and should be downvoted).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Could you perhaps split your question into a question & answer? I think your hammer ideas are good, you should put them in an answer so we can agree/disagree with them :)

Comment: @Lundin I posted as question because it's a feature request. There are already many questions about this problem (I also linked few), I'm warching for good ideas and improvement on such raw sketch

Comment: *"I understand it must be concise (otherwise no one will ever read it)..."* The people you're talking about won't read it anyway.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, help is for whom cares (newbies who simply don't think to read help center - maybe because used to other sites). XyzHammer is for whom doesn't care. If they hardly will get any answer (and they're also warned about that) then they'll be discouraged (I often saw same user posting such questions because somehow they get an answer - that they don't even _accept_).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what do you mean *"Downvote them, downvote the answers too. They will be automatically deleted,"*?? how does a downvoted post get deleted **automatically**??

Comment: *"If question has a **negative** score than RequirementsDumpHammer applies and question can be closed with a single gold badge user."* - Since we are talking about closing the questions **immediately**, i don't think negative score makes much difference - a golde badge user probably has 115 rep, he can simply downvote and hammer it :)

Comment: @TJ a downvoted **and closed** post that matches some requirements (I don't remember exactly but there is a post on meta) will be automatically deleted BUT if there is an answer then it will not...

Comment: @TJ I agree, probably hammer owners can judge alone, no need for downvotes

Comment: What do you mean by "gold badge users should also be able to close questions"? They can already close dupe questions tagged with tags for which they have a gold badge, yes, but do you mean they should also be able to close them as a poor question/unclear?

Also, "if DupeHammer is accepted and in use, then there's nothing wrong with extending the "hammer" power to other close reasons." this is a logical fallacy. We should look to see if there are in fact drawbacks to giving close powers for other reasons, separate from the "close as dupe" power that gold badge users already have.

Comment: @TylerH yes they can already close questions but I'd give them power to close questions faster (for some kind of close reasons). With "...accepted and in use..." I mean: single vote to close (at least for dupes) passed successfully its test and now it's not something new. It may be a good time to try something else (results won't be obscured by other changes).

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti good read, totally agree with the keywords, I just know when I see the word 'please' = low quality question that will soon be closed.

Comment: "**Unclear What Help You Need** is really what we want here. The extra detail could then be: _Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your code needs to be corrected or explained. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._" ([What is a better name for Unclear What You're Asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215806/165773))

Comment: "I think a gold badge user should also have privileges to quickly close such questions" - I am more enthusiastic about question closure. I think *the system* should have privileges to close questions initially with *zero* votes, and do this *every time*. The onus should be on the community to open (what we currently call "reopen") the question after verifying that it meets site standards.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Don't confuse work orders with "how do I do this specific thing" questions.

"How to" questions are the most valuable of all questions, if the answer is general enough to help other programmers.  We want those questions.  We want the answers to those questions.  Long live code samples.

Work orders are another story.  We already have a close reason for those: **Too Broad.**  Use this close reason freely, on those questions where people just want you to complete their project for them.

Comment: Good distinguo, I agree such questions (how to) can get good answers that's why I was talking about questions that can be downvoted but they deserve answers. That said I'd like to see (at least for _gold users_) tools to quickly close "do my task" questions (also to discourage other users to post - sometimes pretty random - answers) but also some help for...who is new. It's easier to come here first time to ask then to answer (IMO).

Comment: _"Work orders are another story. We already have a close reason for those: Too Broad."_ Or (the now gone) `too localized` ?

Comment: But distinction between too broad and too localized is subtle and "how to" questions are closed because they seems "work orders". That's why I would see a better help (very low effort to implement), few checks for common _patterns_ (just very very little effort) and a better tool to close them quickly. If a bad question isn't tagged with popular tags or it doesn't receive a massive amount of downvotes then it may stay open for months. Not such bad but keep site tidy costs a big effort to many people and way used for dupes seems pretty good.

Comment: If in doubt, *don't vote* @Adriano. The hallmark of an overly-broad "workorder" question is that it is unlikely to be answered well or benefit anyone other than the person asking (if even that) - so if you're wrong by not voting, it's just cruft that'll eventually fade away and probably even get deleted automatically. Whereas, if you're wrong *by voting to close*, it's possible you'll deprive others of a useful HOWTO. Considering the very worst offenders are... pretty blatant... it doesn't really pay to worry about edge cases.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree _when in doubt is better to don't vote_. I'm thinking when we're not in doubt. To quickly close such questions will discourage answers too (now it's even pretty common to see _not so bad_ answers downvoted because of that questions and I think this is bad too).

Comment: Then what I was thinking about is to 1) help (of course as [T.J said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270903/how-to-reduce-and-quickly-close-questions-that-are-merely-requirements?noredirect=1#comment92723_270903) for whom cares) newbies and 2) to _strongly discourage_ "do my job" questions (quickly closing, virtually without a chance to get an answer).

Comment: I definitely do not understand how something as specific as "complete this *specific project*" could be considered too *broad*. The difference between broad and localized isn't "subtle" (sorry @AdrianoRepetti); they're *antonyms*. Too extensive, maybe....

Comment: @KyleStrand: The great thing about closing Work Order questions is that they are almost always Too Broad.  If they're *not* too broad, then they're not Work Order questions.

Comment: @KyleStrand too broad because _question_ is too broad (I need this and that, how to do it?) but too localized because who needs it (and who will ever need it) is only OP (unless someone else has exactly same requirements but in that case it's a "how to" question and it _may_ be welcome).

Comment: Robert and @Adriano, would you agree with the examples of "too broad" questions [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857/1858225)? Because those are more along the lines of what I think when I see "too broad"--general questions asking for information about a broad topic area. A work order would have much more particular requirements, making it much more specific (and therefore narrow).

Comment: @KyleStrand those are _too broad_ questions I would vote to close. Some _broad_ questions are _how to_ and "usually" I don't vote to close them if they may be an interesting for future readers (well this subjective, I know). Requirements are both "too broad" (in the sense they don't ask about a small specific point) and "too narrow" (probably no one else will ever have same requirements so code is useful only for OP).

Comment: @KyleStrand: Work Order questions are too broad for the same reasons that we don't provide extended tutorials on Stack Overflow.  It's the scope of the work required.

Comment: Hence my suggestion of "extensive." I suppose that's a reasonable definition of "broad," though, and that the real issue is that it's just not (to me) an intuitive match for the concept being described, in addition to which it seems like it's covering two separate issues (questions with broad scope and project-assignments requiring extensive work).

Comment: @KyleStrand: The description is clear enough.  It says "There are too many possible answers, or **good answers would be too long.**"

Comment: Clear enough for whom? I realize it's clear to *you* that "good answers (to too-broad questions) would be too long" implies "work order questions fit in the too broad category", but it wasn't clear to me until you made it explicit, and I don't think I'm the first person to have this issue. I realize I'm not going to dissuade you, but "too broad" still just doesn't feel *right* to me. I'm not saying I'm going to fight to change it or that I'll refuse to flag these questions that way, just that I don't think this issue is as obvious as you seem to think.

Comment: @KyleStrand: At the moment, it's all we have.

Answer (score -26):

I'm thinking about this at various times. We could have a "side" site, with the most useful Q/A (question/answer) combination... and in body could be ... a different type of problem but related

For example:

How to add a color in font (HTML)?

> A: Put this  ## Really don't answer (it's only an example.)
>
> Alternative A: You could use a ID or NAME:
> --->blah,blah
> ---> Then in a separate CSS you initialize it (..).
> An alternative question how to color (another language or framework)

I know this is a deep work, but (I think) this can help for "jumping" some useless and repeated question.

Comment: The sort of question you're outlining isn't much of a problem. "How do I <complicated set of LoB requirements>" is another matter, and one I don't particularly think would be well-received on *any* site.