# Should a question be closed if it conforms to the precedent set by a popular question?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, closed-questions

Today Apple announced the iPhone 6 and the new resolution sizes. I searched Stack Overflow for any knowledge base on the effect the changes will have for developers. There was nothing. However, I did note that [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) was asked regarding the iPhone 5 when it came out and was wildly popular (protected, and #16 of 267,758 ios questions).

I had recently [read on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270989/should-i-answer-good-questions-for-which-the-op-has-not-tried-anything-no-effor) that if a question is truly useful then original research to solve the problem is not relevant.

> If a question is clear, useful, interesting, well defined and
>   otherwise fits all the criteria we look for in a good question, then
>   it's of no consequence how much effort the OP has or hasn't put into
>   solving their own problem first.

Based on this, I determined that it would be a valuable question to ask the community, and many others would find it useful in the coming months as people start to transition their apps. So I [asked the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751369/support-iphone-6-screen-resolution-along-with-other-resolutions-universally) about dealing with the new iPhone 6 resolutions. It was immediately down-voted, closed and I was flamed ("you should know better", "use your brain", etc). Most comments have since been deleted.

My question is, if this form of question was voted on by the iOS community as not only being relevant, but one of the most valuable questions ever asked, how is it that the iPhone 6 version of the question should be closed and down-voted? If the community as a whole says it's very important in one instance, I just can't see the logic to the opposite response in another instance.

Comment: Was that a genuine question?  Did the advice in that old thread not apply when you tried it on a 6?  Why didn't you document that in your question?  Come to think of it, how did you actually get your hands on one?  As you perhaps found out, SO users have a high bar for *practical* questions.

Comment: For comparison, @HansPassant, the iPhone 5 version of the question was also asked before the device was for sale. App authors needed to know what to change before users got their hands on the phones. But I largely agree with the rest of your comment.

Comment: Yes, it's a genuine question. Apple has never changed the screen width of an iPhone before and understanding how it scales for existing apps will be hugely important. The phone comes out in a few weeks.

Comment: The Apple developers site would be the place that necessary changes to your code would be described, I'd think, particularly since no one here presumably has access to the device for testing either. I'm not personally convinced that the iPhone 5 question you link should have stayed open. It's in essence a list question ("What sorts of things might require change?") instead of a specific question in line with the normal site guidelines here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Site scope is determined by current community gestalt, not historical precedent.   You cannot, therefore, point to an old post as evidence that you can ask a new question.

Let's take a look at the original Stack Overflow question you cited. Despite it's legitimate appearance, this question actually has a bit of a troubled past.

1. It has 34 answers.  **Thirty four.** That's not a good sign; it is evidence that the question is Too Broad (there are too many possible answers).  It is also a red flag that the community may be [painting the bikeshed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality).
2. The question went through a close/reopen cycle.  A moderator rescued it by attempting to better focus the question by editing it, and then unilaterally reopening it.
3. Seven deleted answers, 28 moderator flags, 25 deleted comments.

Not stellar, by any means.  Of course, you can chalk up some of that (especially voting) to the sheer number of views the question has received.  Hopefully, the content there is of sufficient quality that it's not wasting the time of all those visitors.  Popularity doesn't always correlate with usefulness.

Beyond all that, the comments below your Stack Overflow question say it all:

> There's invariably an annoying flood of questions about the new stuff immediately after every Apple announcement. You seem to be suffering a pre-emptive backlash to this one. You might have gotten a better response if you had done some research yourself, instead of imitating the iPhone 5 question, which has predictably gathered a lot of cruft. I am on the fence about voting to reopen this. Precedent has been set, yes, but I'm not sure it's a good precedent.

Comment: So are you saying the iPhone 5 question from a year ago, voted by the community to be in the top 0.01% in category popularity, should be closed as being outside the current community gestalt? I don't see how you can close one and not the other. I'm sure you can understand my confusion as to how the gestalt can be so  contradictory from one moment to the next.

Comment: @Robert: It sounds like the iPhone 5 version of the question needs to be placed under historical lock... the wording of that explicitly covers imitation questions.

Comment: @BenVoigt that would technically resolve the issue. However, if you step back, do you really want to discourage a question that the community found so valuable and helpful over the past few years (which is not that historical)? The evidence suggests it's a much more valuable question than the typical fix-the-bug-in-my-code question.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I want to explicitly say that copycatting a list question is not a good idea.  Really, it would be better if people didn't look at old questions at all for purposes of topicality -- the binding rules are the current on-topic FAQ.

Comment: A long as the question is clear and people are happy to answer, leave it alone.
Search engines good a good job of picking out relevant questions, there is no value in 
closing reasonable questions. There is no
need to close a question, if people are happy helping each other out.

Comment: @eddyparkinson: It doesn't really work that way here.  Try to remember the last time you actually got a useful, relevant answer from a forum, where people don't close questions or even moderate, really.  Can't remember?  I didn't think so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Imagine adding the ability to close questions to a forum, how much better do you thing that would make things?  ... I suspect you would mostly drive people away. ....  In contrast there are just as many 'not so great' questions on StackOverflow as there are an an average forum, having the close is not making much difference ... . .. I suggest it is the points and votes that is having the big impact, closing is making little difference.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry to keep going on with this ... but it has bothered me for a long time.

How does the close improve the site? It helps keep out the jerks, it is needed. But the site is 
full of 'not so great' questions and yet this looks to have little impact on the site. So how
 is the close helping?

Comment: @eddyparkinson: Stack Exchange attracts experts by keeping things *interesting.*  Let's face it: vast avalanches of homework questions and "what is the best thingadongdong to frob the foo" are not all that interesting, which is why it's so hard to find answers to questions on forums... I noticed that you dodged my question about getting any meaningful help from a forum.  If people want to hang out and "chew the fat" on a forum, that's fine, but it doesn't solve anyone's programming problem, which is actually why we're here.

Comment: @eddyparkinson: In short, we don't want to have to sift through mountains of chaff to get to the wheat.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did not dodge, I just don't agree ... I don't agree that the close is the reason that there are high quality questions and answers on Stack Exchange. I don't see the evidence. The evidence I see suggests other things are producing the quality. As I said, There are many hum drum questions on here, the close is just not getting rid of the hum drum, as you suggest it is, the site is full of hum drum.