# Is it all just opinion?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, closed-questions

As I have used Stack Overflow, as well as the larger network, a common recent experience has been that questions are characterized as "opinion based", which is then given as a reason for then closing.

Some questions one may conceive plainly are matters of opinion, such as identifying a favorite programming language.

Others are clearly factual. I have found one question ([Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862)) that leaves very little room for discussion, and has proved quite popular. I doubt though it gives anyone an opportunity to achieve some great leap of comprehension.

I found another question ([Groovy / Scala / Java under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529736)) that is  more discursive and general, targeting differences in programming languages. It has been far less popular, compared to the one given above, measured by vote count, but surely has survived, and inspired many detailed and enthusiastic answers.

Generally, the characterization as an opinion is given to that which has little or no ability to be corroborated independently, especially matters of speculation and preference, or to be discussed toward the convergence of rational consensus.

In comparison to the above question about Groovy and Scala, which is targeted, but also heavily laden in personal experience and indirection of objective, I have addressed the same general subject domain by posting my own question ([Groovy, Kotlin, Scala: JVM-compatible languages current usage patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74610071)). It was quite broad, but also clear, direct, accessible, detailed, germane, and as far as I know, and I would be happy to learn otherwise, accurate. Certainly, its nature was of heavy orientation around objective characterizations.

Yet, it was closed, and characterized as an opinion.

Why?

[The guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) include the following remarks (quoted selectively for brevity and relevance): "Some subjective questions are allowed... Constructive subjective questions [are those that]... inspire answers that explain *why* and *how*... tend to have long, not short, answers... have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone... are more than just mindless social fun." It strikes me that these characterizations align closely with the question.

A robust answer would be possible, one grounded on uncontroversial observations and elucidating a space attracting wide interest. It has not been asked which  of the languages is superior, even for some purpose, only the differences, of which many might be corroborated even by their designers.

Yet, instead, we have elevated to highest esteem learning how to change character case. Do we truly wish to be so narrow, as a community?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250030/discussion-on-question-by-brainchild-is-it-all-just-opinion).

Answer (score 27):

Your core question:

> Compared to Java, how are each of these languages (Groovy, Kotlin, Scala) currently being used across science and industry in enterprise, desktop, mobile, administrative, and analytics applications?

Or presented visually:
[image]

Where each cell in this question matrix could easily require a book chapter or more to answer properly, and given the complexity and broad reach of the information requested would likely generate multiple and differing opinions (a key word here) leading to lengthy discussions, and disagreements, all making the question wholly unsuitable for this site.

And as per my comments, I am not stating that it is a *bad question*, and in fact, it has been presented rather well, but rather that it is a *bad fit* for this site.

---

Further more, you state in comments,

> "SE already has natural methods for determining how much a community values a question or answer"

It has three such mechanisms, member voting whereby members rate a Q or A's perceived overall quality and research effort, member close voting whereby "trusted" members are allowed to vote on whether a question is on-topic or not, and member delete voting whereby members vote if a question should be deleted. None of these mechanisms are considered "natural" or "artificial" but rather they allowed mechanisms for members to express their views on a question.

> "...which cannot be effectual if questions are killed artificially by a judgment in defiance of those methods..."

Again, none of the mechanisms described are considered artificial or natural, but rather mechanisms that the site allows to allow member curation of the site. But you are implying that some of these decisions are *"in defiance"* of some "natural method"? What is natural? Who are you, or me or anyone to judge this? We have tools and we use them as best we can, in what we, the individual members, perceive are the best interests of the site.

If one of us disagrees with this decision, then a common mechanism for seeing if the decision was felt to be poor by the involved community is to pose a question on meta and see how the involved membership votes. I think that you/we are seeing these results, and the results appear to be unambiguous.

Comment: "*I am not stating that it is a bad question, and in fact, it has been presented rather well, but rather that it is a bad fit for this site.*" Yes, I am agreeing, but also substantially asking whether the reason for its being a poor fit for "this site" is the platform design of the site, or simply the insularity of thinking among the community.

Comment: @brainchild: *"... the platform design of the site, or simply the insularity of thinking among the community?"* -- by what metric can this ever be determined? How can your meta post or the discussion that it generates possibly determine this?

Comment: @brainchild: There is no "Deus ex machina" here to bestow judgement from on high, just our own individual opinions, unless you're looking for input from the site owners, and we very likely won't see that coming for this discussion.

Comment: I am not measuring the minds of those who participate on the platform, only trying to discover why so many resist changing them. The question (on Meta, not the original) invites consideration of the broader nuance above any knee-jerk objections. There is no judgment from on high, just yours, and everyone else's. Why not be more receptive? If you can't speak for others, then speak for yourself, but do so not just against me, but toward and among everyone at large.

Comment: @brainchild: my own personal views are that this site has survived and in fact thrived, while others have fallen by the wayside just because it strives to encourage questions and answers that are highly focused, that are directly helpful to me and fellow coders and help us to fix our bugs or improve our code. The site (again) encourages member curation to separate the wheat from the chaff, to let the better questions and answers rise to the top and to let those that are much less directly helpful, less factual, to sink to the bottom. That is my opinion.

Comment: @brainchild: And this has been how the site has worked for most of its life. That you're desiring to keep your main-site question alive on the site is evidence that you have found the site useful and wish to help contribute to it, further evidence in the success of the site's model. I can understand your frustration with your question's being closed, but again, I do agree with its closure.

Comment: If a question has no good answers, then it is not ultimately helpful. If it is closed, then it cannot receive answers. Thus, the methods in some sense obstruct the objects, without providing any equitable benefit. It was decided that the question cannot be well answered, though not by not being well answered, but rather by being prevented from in any way being answered. Meanwhile, if it is not prevented from being answered, but yet not well answered, then the effect is the same, but none may have known except by allowing the opportunity. Such in my frustration.

Comment: The analysis expressed in the graphic reveals an enthusiasm to reject a different perspective by considering it through only the most narrow and insular of all lenses. Yes, a "book chapter" might address each of the separate questions, but the core matter may also be addressed in other ways both cogent and succinct. Please present objections without invoking a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) characterization.

Comment: It tends to emerge, as to some degree latent in those sentiments originally presented, that the characterization of opinion is, more than many may concede, itself informed by one's own opinions, which may not be well for one to impose onto another.

Comment: @brainchild: The upvote/downvote  button is all about using our opinions and imposing them on others. It's the theory of the site. The same with close votes and everything else.

Comment: Looking at some of your other questions, you seem to be looking for a discussion in many of them. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion site.

Comment: @Pres If someone would cast a down vote in an instance that the same vote would not have been considered except following from an author referencing his own question on Meta, then the behavior may aggregate toward a sort of [chilling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_effect) against legitimate discussion. I am asking separation of the activities relating to the discussion of a question versus the more regular interaction with it. Please don't vote down if you have seen the question only following from the reference on Meta. Doing so distorts the overall process.

Comment: @brainchild: I only cast my vote based on the content of the question, and only if I believe I am qualified to pass that judgement. I might not otherwise have seen that question if not for the discussion here, but my vote is not influenced by what is said here.

Comment: @Pres, It's not the issue. The issue is the reason you became aware of the question, and how that reason aggregates into group behavior. I would not have drawn attention to the question if it had not already received a negative response. It is harmful to compound the metric for the original response through a second-order effect, one whose course was determined by the earlier events.

Comment: @brainchild: However, by "this is a question and answer site" I meant stackoverflow specifically and not Meta.

Answer (score 16):

> Yet. instead, we have elevated to highest esteem learning how to change character case. Do we truly wish to be so narrow, as a community?

Yes, we do. The community doesn't want broad, opinion-based discussion threads, just practical programming questions and answers. There are other sites for discussion that may offer an "anything goes" atmosphere, like Quora and Reddit.

If you think SO is too narrowly scoped, consider that there are 23 million questions on the site at the time of writing, with thousands of new questions posted per day. Curating that body of knowledge takes a huge amount of work (mostly by volunteers), so narrow focus is critical to keeping the site the usable resource that it has been for over a decade.

From the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour):

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

From the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) topic in our help center:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

The question you shared and the [12-year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529736/groovy-scala-java-under-the-hood) you referenced in your post as justification for it don't appear to be within the bounds of these guidelines regardless of whether they're interesting or well-asked in their own right.

Many old threads were posted before the community had the standards it does now and continue to exist either for historical purposes or because they've evaded curation, but would be off-topic if asked today.

Furthermore, the [Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case) question you cited is also not a particularly great question since it shows no obvious attempt or research. It just happens to have picked a piece of low-hanging fruit back in 2008 and became a canonical resource for a common, practical and answerable problem.

Comment: I understand the sense of the remarks. I believe I have tried to express a view that the question I presented might be addressed by rambling discussions, but such is not the only approach. An answer is possible that is consistent with the broader ambitions, expectations, and constraints of the platform, and such is what I have sought. If it would be allowed that someone might attempt to present a succinct, robust, no-nonsense answer, then the particular platform would be the one ideally suited for it.

Comment: I agree with most all of your statements above (1+), but reluctantly, not this one: *"In fact, the Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case question you cited is also off-topic since it shows no obvious attempt or research."* -- this is a valid reason to *down-vote* a question on this site but is not a reason for a question to be considered off-topic. Please see [Should I answer good questions for which the OP has not tried anything (no effort at all)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270989/522444) and multiple other meta discussions that review this topic.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd vote to close it as "too broad" if it wasn't canonical. It's missing context and a concrete attempt, so there's no way to help OP fix a _specific_ code issue. The only answers can be "I guess you want something like X". For this particular question, it just so happens that there's little room to misinterpret it, but usually no-attempt questions like this require many assumptions and guesswork to answer, and so they're usually off-topic and broad or unclear. The concrete attempt and research is necessary to clarify to scope of the question and the use case context.

Comment: @ggorlen: that is your opinion, but I don't think that it is the view of the majority of site users or of the "Gods who walked before us", e.g., Shog9. Please also have a look at [Robert Harvey's answer to a similar issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270938/522444). But I/we digress from the main thrust of this discussion and you and I should possibly discuss this elsewhere and on some other more relevant question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, we're getting off-topic, but you think the lowercase question wouldn't be close-voted instantly in 2022, even if it hadn't been asked before? I don't think it'd last long at all.

Comment: Questions like the "convert JS string to lowercase one" are not only good and on-topic, but **among the most important ones on the site**. [Be careful not to conflate types of effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828). Given that the purpose of questions **is not** to help OP, but to *build a knowledge base*, it stands to reason that trivial topics **need** to be included. You know, like how Wikipedia has a page about dogs.

Comment: The reason for caring about "attempt or research" is because it clarifies and focuses the question - the first step of any attempt at a *task* is to break it down into the actual *problems* that have actual *questions* underlying them. The lowercase question wouldn't last long if it hadn't been asked before - because people would assume it had been asked before, and get annoyed by it. They would, however, be wrong to close it.

Comment: Sure, trivial topics need to be included, but they should at least show some constructive attempt beyond essentially "gimme teh codez". The lowercase thread at hand is a bit of an edge case, but for every no-effort question that happens to become canonical because it was the first one to pick the fruit, there are thousands that are essentially worthless for the site. Anomalies happen and sometimes poorly-asked questions still become incredibly useful from time to time in spite of themselves. Nonetheless, I rephrased my statement to make it reflect my opinion rather than a fact.

Comment: I don't see a problem with closing no-effort questions that deal with trivial issues even if it's the first to pick the fruit, because there's always a better canonical that'll show up sooner or later that has a crisp attempt and shows research. Such a question makes the canonical much stronger, more useful, and more reflective of the site's tone and values. Besides, it's 2022, not 2008, and the site is mature, so it's OK that new content is held to a different standard. There's only so much value in analyzing the merits of 14-year old content so I didn't intend to make it more than an aside.

Comment: Quora is now roamed by senseless moderation bots of unspecified IQ, so those questions may not even be accepted there. Though it may be possible to find an existing question from before the Bottageddon.

Comment: "The community doesn't want broad, opinion-based discussion threads" - not so sure about that, the plenty of other available sites prove otherwise. That is why it is kind of a blessing that Stack Overflow exists to focus on facts in between all those heated personal opinions. The discussions can be held elsewhere, no need to force them into a site specifically designed not to have them.