# How to deal with business requirements?

Tags: discussion, support

I just stumbled up on this question [files need to sites/default/files/copies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33844160/5297359).

I flagged it as *too broad*, but I think it´s (not really) *too broad*.

I just found no flag for: *this looks like business requirements, from a customer :)*

Is there another category for that, or is *too broad* OK?

Due to the (duplicate) comments I found this as [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270938/5297359) for me:

> Work orders are another story. We already have a close reason for
>   those: Too Broad. Use this close reason freely, on those questions
>   where people just want you to complete their project for them.

Comment: It suffices. I usually tend to go for "unclear what you're asking", given that there is no stated question regarding the particular problems they are facing. But either would be fine imho.

Comment: "Please write this for me" (and sometimes, *in extremis*, "Write this for me!") are not really "Unclear what you are asking". At times the entire exercise gets posted, so it's hardly 'unclear'. For me it's just "too broad"; mostly I don't even bother to write a custom close reason.

Comment: thanks and sorry for bothering, didn't found the answers myself^^